# Media Queries does not load

Tags: wordpress, css, media-queries, genesis

I am working on this website http://www.passiveincomekube.com/violeta/ and I am testing responsiveness here studiopress dot com/responsive/ ,I wrote Media Query for these screen sizes `@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px)` `@media only screen and (max-width: 1139px)` `@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px)` and if I can see my website here studiopress dot com/responsive/ ,the responsiveness works till 768 px devices .

I am writing Media Query for now `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` device ,it is not working and still loading previous media query that is for `1023px` one

Is there any solution so that it loads Media query for this and below devices `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)`

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see your site right now, your `style.css` contains three media queries for 1023px (line 2014, line 2645, and line 2823) but none for 768px. Perhaps you forgot to update the server?

Comment: Hi Maximillian,I just checked ,I removed it but situation is same ,it does not load `767px` media Query

Comment: Your css file has quite a few syntax errors in it (mostly extra curly braces) that are preventing the browser from reading your media query. Look at the lines where the validator says "Parse Error": https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.passiveincomekube.com%2Fvioleta%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fmagazine-pro%2Fstyle.css%3Fver%3D3.1&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en